# Display Img and Div inline - it's not rendered inline

Tags: html, inline, image

In order to follow correct web standards, I've tried to layout image and div inline. In orde to achieve that - I've used display:inline property. 
But then I experienced the following issue: image renders from the center line, and div doesn't respect height parameter set to it. I've tried using line-height parameter, but that didn't give any useful results.
I've also tried various combinations with setting margin/padding to some values or to auto, or replacing div with span, or wrapping img and div with additional divs.
I've managed to achieve desired result by using position:absolute, but that doesn't help in cases where I want to use centered/relative positioning of the whole component...

Any clues or ideas or troubleshooting hints?

Please find the html example below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>      
    <div style="border: solid 2px green; height:40px;width: 600px;">
        <span style="border:solid 2px green; position: absolute; height:50px; width: 50px;">
            <i m g 
          style="display:inline; margin: 3px; padding:0px; border: solid 2px lightblue;"
            height="38px"
            width="38px" 
            src="someimage . JPG"
        />
        </span>
        <span style="position:absolute; left: 100px; width:400px; height:60px; margin:3px; border: solid 2px red;">
            Some text that should be displayed in the center/middle of the div
        </span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="border: solid 2px green; height:80px;width: 600px;">
        <span style="border:solid 2px green; position: absolute; height:50px; width: 50px; vertical-align:bottom;">
            123
        </span>
        &nbsp;
        <span style="position:absolute; left: 100px; width:400px; height:60px; margin:3px; border: solid 2px red;">
            Some text that should be displayed in the center/middle of the div
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A code sample would help a ton, but try using `display: inline-block;` instead and see if that gets closer to what you are after.

Comment: You cannot assign a height to `inline` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help out.

First - the solution:
I've added few attributes to image tag and that helped a lot:
hspace="0" vspace="0" align="top" border="0"

Second: explanation:
Since I wanted to do "inline" (or "inline-block") thing, I had to figure out how inline/inline-block elements are laid-out by browsers. If you read CSS2 layout spec, you will soon find out that there is an issue with image and divs. Problem is with vertical-align - where image is aligned/rendered comparing to baseline, while divs go for bottom-line (or vice versa). That caused my example not be aligned.
Setting above mentioned params for the image tag helped.

Remarks: 
Due to the complex history of IE5,6,7, Firefox, Gecko, WebKit, Chrome, CSS2 and BoxModel, there are some shortcomings to Layout model. Original problem comes from IE5 and 6 handling BoxModel in different way from CSS standard. That's maybe the main reason for having quirks mode and DTD standards.
However, this is a broad topic, if you want to find out more, I recoomend readin CSS2 spec and recommendation.
If you want to discuss it more - feel free to contact me via PM

Thanks again to all for helping and good luck with your Layouts

Kind regards
MP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;"></div>
```

It's actually part of the [CSS2 standard](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) to display an inline thing as a block like a character.

One thing is, though, that `<div>`s are not supposed to occur inside of a `<p>` element, so you should instead use `<span>` tags.

Comment: Older versions of IE don't like `inline-block` on default `block` elements. Use a default `inline` element such as a span instead.

Comment: @Joel Potter - Read the original question; he wanted a block-level element with a `height` and `width` property. And older versions of IE are pretty much not to be trifled with since Google stopped supporting them.

Comment: A `<span style="display:inline-block">` is exactly the same as a `<div style="display:inline-block">`. The only difference is more browsers support it. Why not go with the wider supported approach? (Just because Google does something doesn't mean everyone will or must or can.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. But it sounds like you want to float an image left with text in the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
<style>
.wrap {
    border: solid 2px green;
    width: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.myimg {
    display:inline; 
    margin: 10px; 
    padding:0px; 
    border:solid 2px green; 
    height:70px; width: 70px;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>      
    <div class="wrap">
        <img src="myimagepath" class="myimg" />
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```